# echo database data to html php pdo

Tags: php, html, pdo

i have a database select on load of html on the select statement i select the last five in descending or here is the code

loadevent.php

```
<?php 
function LoadEvent(){
    global $dbh;
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM events ORDER by event_id DESC LIMIT 5") ;
    //$stmt->bindValue(1,$eventwhat);
    $stmt->execute();
    while($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
        $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'] = $selected_row['event_what'];
        $_SESSION['searchresultwhere'] = $selected_row['event_where'];
        $_SESSION['searchresultwhen'] = $selected_row['event_when'];
        $_SESSION['searchresultwho'] = $selected_row['event_who'];
        $event = array($_SESSION['searchresultwhat'] => $selected_row['event_what'], $_SESSION['searchresultwhere'] =>$selected_row['event_where'], $_SESSION['searchresultwhen'] =>$selected_row['event_when'],$_SESSION['searchresultwho'] =>$selected_row['event_who']);
        $_SESSION['arr'] = $event;

        foreach ($_SESSION['arr'] as $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'] => $selected_row['event_what']){
            echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'];
            echo "<br/>\n";
        }
    }

}       
?>
```

and in my html at top page i write

index.php

```
<?php include_once("include/loadevent.php");
    LoadEvent();?>
```

in html my code is

```
<?php
    foreach ($_SESSION['arr'] as $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'] => $selected_row['event_what']){
        echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'];
        echo "<br/>\n";
    }
?>
```

when i do echo from loadevent.php i get the last five in descending order but in index all i get is the first event and nothing more why is it that way can anyone see where my mistake is?

Comment: why you are saving in session, while loop the $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'] overwrite its value. The last loop value only stored in $_SESSION['searchresultwhat']. Thats why returned only one value, I think.

Comment: `$selected_row['event_what']` in the HTML code will have only the last value you fetched from the database,since it is used outside the while statement.

Comment: You are really, really abusing the $_SESSION vars here. I have a code sample coming up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing some very odd things with the $_SESSION var, and as far as I can see there is no reason at all. Try this:

```
<?php

    function LoadEvent()
    {
        global $dbh;

        $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM events ORDER by event_id DESC LIMIT 5") ;
        $stmt->execute();

        $events = array();

        while ($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $events[] = array(
                'searchresultwhat'  => $selected_row['event_what'],
                'searchresultwhere' => $selected_row['event_where'],
                'searchresultwhen'  => $selected_row['event_when'],
                'searchresultwho'   => $selected_row['event_who']
            );
        }

        // Is this just for testing? Or should it be echoing stuff all the time?
        // foreach ($events as $key => $value)
        // {
        //     echo $value['searchresultwhat'];
        //     echo "<br/>\n";
        // }

        // This is completely optional and should be removed if you don't
        // use the $_SESSION method later on in your HTML 
        $_SESSION['arr'] = $events;

        return $events;
    }
?>
```

...and then in your HTML, do this:

```
<?php

    foreach ($_SESSION['arr'] as $value)
    {
        echo $value['searchresultwhat'];
        echo "<br/>\n";
    }

?>
```

Or, **even better** in your index.php do this:

```
<?php

    include_once("include/loadevent.php");

?>
```

Then in your HTML, you can avoid the $_SESSION all together:

```
<?php

    foreach (LoadEvent() as $value)
    {
        echo $value['searchresultwhat'];
        echo "<br/>\n";
    }

?>
```

Comment: really amazing one question please...the reason why i use session is because when i dont the variable i use will not have value if i dont use session i mean it always give me undefined index how did you do please explain

Comment: Most likely because I set the `$events = array();` (an empty array) initially. That makes sure that even if the SQL query returns nothing, there's at least something for the foreach() loops to start on. Without at least an empty array, you will get undefined index errors.

Comment: so basically i dont need to put all the variables in session if i want to access it in html?

Comment: You only need to store the data in the $_SESSION vars if you need it to persist (stick around) between page loads. You don't need it at all if you are just including files with functions, etc.

Comment: yes for example i search data in database and show it in html i need to use session for that?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be to replace `$_SESSION['arr'] = $event;` with `$_SESSION['arr'][] = $event;` AND

```
foreach ($_SESSION['arr'] as $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'] => $selected_row['event_what']){
    echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'];
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
```

with

```
foreach ($_SESSION['arr'] as $value){
    echo $value[$_SESSION['searchresultwhat']];
    echo "<br/>\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in your 'while' loop you overwrite values in `$_SESSION` superglobal:

```
while($selected_row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    //it is overwritten each time you are in while loop
    $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'] = $selected_row['event_what'];
    (...)

    foreach ($_SESSION['arr'] as $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'] => $selected_row['event_what']){
        //in this place when you echo it, it echoes current loop iteration so it is executed 5 times
        echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'];
        echo "<br/>\n";
    }
}
```

being at index.php you do echo of last value only from `while` loop.

Comment: How does the while() loop all of a sudden disappear just because you called the LoadEvent() function in index,php? It still should be `echo $_SESSION['searchresultwhat'];` every iteration.